# Rearranging Serial Data into Parallel data in C

Tags: stm32, dma

I'm building a system to drive a large string of WS2812 RGB LEDs that require a high frequency (800kHz) data signal to be configured.

My system which is currently implemented on a STM32F3 looks like this:

```
Input:
PC (UART)   ->  DMA ->  Memory

Output:
Memory  -> DMA  -> GPIO
```

The issue I'm having is that currently I'm only passing data for a single LED strip (single GPIO) over USART and storing that data in a buffer of uint8_t. However because the DMA moving data from memory to the GPIO needs a minimum of 1 byte of data, I need to convert my USART bit stream into a byte stream essentially. Something like this:

```
USART Data:
  R    G    B
{0xFF, 0xAA, 0x00}

DMA Source:
{0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,     //R
 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00,     //G
 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}     //B
```

Now, the problem is that I have very limited clock cycles to rearrange this data for the DMA.

I'm hoping someone has some algorithm that will do this memory rearranging really efficiently. Otherwise I may try getting rid of the UART DMA and doing interrupt-based reading/rearranging of the data as it comes in.

My only other option is to increase my data throughput from the PC to 8x what it is right now to basically pass in a bunch of 0s.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
unsigned char array[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0xa0, 0xa5};

int i,j;
for ( j = 0; j < sizeof(array); j++ ) {
    printf("array[%d] (0x%02x) bits: ", j, array[j]);
    for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) {
        printf("%d ", (array[j] >> i & 0x01) );
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This outputs:

> array[0] (0x00) bits: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   array[1] (0x01) bits: 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   array[2] (0x02) bits: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   array[3] (0x03) bits: 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   array[4] (0xa0) bits: 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
>   array[5] (0xa5) bits: 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1

to reverse the bits replace the inner loop with

```
for ( i = 7; i >= 0; i-- ) {
    printf("%d ", (array[j] >> i & 0x01) );
}
```

> array[0] (0x00) bits: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   array[1] (0x01) bits: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
>   array[2] (0x02) bits: 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
>   array[3] (0x03) bits: 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
>   array[4] (0xa0) bits: 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
>   array[5] (0xa5) bits: 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1

You won't need the outer loop.  That loop simulates your DMA.  Basically, the inner loop dynamically creates a mask and checks that bit and outputs a 1 if it's set and 0 if it's not.  You can then output that to GPIO.  You should be able to set up an interrupt so that each byte transfer of the DMA runs the code above in the ISR.

Better yet, ditch DMA and just have this happen on UART interrupts.

Comment: Thanks I ended up doing away with the USART DMA